# How to see sort information system.profile (mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I enabled profiling mode 2 (all events). My idea is to write a script, that will go through all the queries and execute explain plans and see whether any of the queries do not use indexes. However it's impossible to do so as I don't see any sorting information in the system.profile. Why so?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Imagine, you have a users collection. And you have created an index on this collection: user(name, createdAt). Now I would like to find out some users sorted by time. In system.profile the second part of the query (sorting/pagination) won't be saved, however it's very important to understand what sorting operation were used, as it affects the performance and index selection.
So my intention was to create a script that will go through all statements in system.profile and execute explain plans and see whether indexes are used or not. If not, I can automatically catch all new/not reliable queries while executing integration tests.

Comment: I'm definitely curious about what the specifics or examples of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why did 10gen choose to not include sorting information in the system.profile?

I'd suggest if you're interested in the feature, to request it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa). (I couldn't find an existing suggestion for this feature). You might get more detail about why it hasn't been included.

I can see how it could be valuable sometimes, although it's recommended that you [compare](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/) the nscanned vs the nreturned as a way of knowing whether indexes are being used (and more importantly, making sure as few documents are scanned as possible).

So, while not perfect, it gives you a quick way of evaluating performance and detecting index usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework to sort
e.g. slowest operations first
`db.system.profile.aggregate( { $sort : { millis : -1 }})`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I found an answer to that question. Actually mongo has it. It's called orderby inside the query element. My bad :-)